# Read XML from Prestashop API (SimpleXMLElement)

Tags: php, xml, api, prestashop

I trying to read the orders of a online shop by Webservice of Prestashop. The connection and read are OK but the problem is when I try to use the data

```
//CONNECTION
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('http://example.com/', 'N1285LRSTHSRTHRTHRTUI5Q9X6', true);

// ORDERS
$xml = $webService->get(['resource' => 'orders','display'=>'full']);

foreach ($xml->order as $order) {
    echo $test = $order->order->payment;
}
```

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<orders>
<order>
    <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
    <module><![CDATA[redsys]]></module>
    <invoice_number><![CDATA[6]]></invoice_number>
    <invoice_date><![CDATA[2020-04-13 15:36:28]]></invoice_date>
    <delivery_number><![CDATA[1]]></delivery_number>
    <delivery_date><![CDATA[2020-04-16 12:19:31]]></delivery_date>
    <valid><![CDATA[1]]></valid>
    <date_add><![CDATA[2020-04-13 15:36:27]]></date_add>
    <date_upd><![CDATA[2020-04-16 12:19:31]]></date_upd>
    <shipping_number notFilterable="true"></shipping_number>
    <id_shop_group><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop_group>
    <id_shop><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop>
    <secure_key><![CDATA[bf1bbed22e8b94bad540cc1f88e69360]]></secure_key>
    <payment><![CDATA[Pago con tarjeta Redsys]]></payment>
    <recyclable><![CDATA[0]]></recyclable>
    <gift><![CDATA[0]]></gift>
    <gift_message></gift_message>
    <mobile_theme><![CDATA[0]]></mobile_theme>
    <total_discounts><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_discounts>
    <total_discounts_tax_incl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_discounts_tax_incl>
    <total_discounts_tax_excl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_discounts_tax_excl>
    <total_paid><![CDATA[169.000000]]></total_paid>
    <total_paid_tax_incl><![CDATA[169.000000]]></total_paid_tax_incl>
    <total_paid_tax_excl><![CDATA[140.000000]]></total_paid_tax_excl>
    <total_paid_real><![CDATA[169.000000]]></total_paid_real>
    <total_products><![CDATA[140.000000]]></total_products>
    <total_products_wt><![CDATA[169.000000]]></total_products_wt>
    <total_shipping><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_shipping>
    <total_shipping_tax_incl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_shipping_tax_incl>
    <total_shipping_tax_excl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_shipping_tax_excl>
    <carrier_tax_rate><![CDATA[0.000]]></carrier_tax_rate>
    <total_wrapping><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_wrapping>
    <total_wrapping_tax_incl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_wrapping_tax_incl>
    <total_wrapping_tax_excl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_wrapping_tax_excl>
    <round_mode><![CDATA[2]]></round_mode>
    <round_type><![CDATA[2]]></round_type>
    <conversion_rate><![CDATA[1.000000]]></conversion_rate>
    <reference><![CDATA[ZEIPWMWWL]]></reference>

</order>
<order>
    <id><![CDATA[2]]></id>
    </current_state>
    <module><![CDATA[redsys]]></module>
    <invoice_number><![CDATA[7]]></invoice_number>
    <invoice_date><![CDATA[2020-04-13 16:18:18]]></invoice_date>
    <delivery_number><![CDATA[2]]></delivery_number>
    <delivery_date><![CDATA[2020-04-15 18:34:15]]></delivery_date>
    <valid><![CDATA[1]]></valid>
    <date_add><![CDATA[2020-04-13 16:18:18]]></date_add>
    <date_upd><![CDATA[2020-04-15 18:34:15]]></date_upd>
    <shipping_number notFilterable="true"></shipping_number>
    <id_shop_group><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop_group>
    <id_shop><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop>
    <secure_key><![CDATA[9a2da2a2dd2808e9c276e877fc4cc387]]></secure_key>
    <payment><![CDATA[Pago con tarjeta Redsys]]></payment>
    <recyclable><![CDATA[0]]></recyclable>
    <gift><![CDATA[0]]></gift>
    <gift_message></gift_message>
    <mobile_theme><![CDATA[0]]></mobile_theme>
    <total_discounts><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_discounts>
    <total_discounts_tax_incl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_discounts_tax_incl>
    <total_discounts_tax_excl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_discounts_tax_excl>
    <total_paid><![CDATA[139.000000]]></total_paid>
    <total_paid_tax_incl><![CDATA[139.000000]]></total_paid_tax_incl>
    <total_paid_tax_excl><![CDATA[115.000000]]></total_paid_tax_excl>
    <total_paid_real><![CDATA[139.000000]]></total_paid_real>
    <total_products><![CDATA[115.000000]]></total_products>
    <total_products_wt><![CDATA[139.000000]]></total_products_wt>
    <total_shipping><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_shipping>
    <total_shipping_tax_incl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_shipping_tax_incl>
    <total_shipping_tax_excl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_shipping_tax_excl>
    <carrier_tax_rate><![CDATA[0.000]]></carrier_tax_rate>
    <total_wrapping><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_wrapping>
    <total_wrapping_tax_incl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_wrapping_tax_incl>
    <total_wrapping_tax_excl><![CDATA[0.000000]]></total_wrapping_tax_excl>
    <round_mode><![CDATA[2]]></round_mode>
    <round_type><![CDATA[2]]></round_type>
    <conversion_rate><![CDATA[1.000000]]></conversion_rate>
    <reference><![CDATA[VNXLLJTGV]]></reference>
</order>
</orders>
</prestashop>
```

if I try the payment method with $order->order->payment; the foreach only read the first order, but I have 320 orders on the XML..

I have been with this problem for many hours and I think that is a silly mistake...

Comment: Based on your sample xml, what's your expected output?

Comment: All the data of an order. I'm trying only with <payment> so I expected the <payment> of all orders...

Comment: You have to be more specific: for `<payment>` in your xml, is your expected output `Pago con tarjeta Redsys` twice?

Comment: Yes, but i need this output for all orders. My output only shows the <payment> of first order

Answer (score 1):

I won't do it for all your nodes, but here's something with 3 random nodes you can try on your actual xml:

```
$my_doc = new DOMDocument();
$my_doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($my_doc);
$result = $xpath->query("//payment  | //total_products_wt | //total_products");

foreach($result as $value){
    echo $value->nodeValue . "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
Pago con tarjeta Redsys
140.000000
169.000000
Pago con tarjeta Redsys
115.000000
139.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON instead of XML for output format:

```
https://Your-Site-Domain/api/orders?output_format=JSON
```

And for order details (id=1):

```
https://Your-Site-Domain/api/orders/1?output_format=JSON
```